# How to cut and paste a same column as a next column in a new dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 60 data frames. I have to select 4th column in each data frame and add it a new frame so that this new matrix will have 60 columns.

```py
data = total_data.append(df[3])
```

I am not getting 60 columns. Instead, I am getting a single column with all data. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this?

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data = [x.iloc[:, 3] for x in list_of_frames]).T
```

This will take the column you want, and make it a row in a new frame. Then transpose the dataframe.

I tried this with some random data, and it worked for me.

This way feels dumb, but works as well:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for n,i in enumerate(list_of_frames):
    df_new['{}_column'.format(n)] = i['4th_column']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

#### random data:

```
data = {'a': [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(10)],
        'b': [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(10)],
        'c': [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(10)],
        'd': [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(10)],
        'e': [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(10)]}

data = {'a': [6, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6, 1, 3, 9, 1],
        'b': [1, 7, 8, 9, 3, 8, 7, 7, 9, 2],
        'c': [9, 2, 3, 0, 6, 7, 9, 2, 8, 7],
        'd': [0, 1, 5, 7, 6, 0, 0, 7, 8, 0],
        'e': [2, 8, 8, 6, 5, 2, 1, 0, 3, 8]}
```

#### dict of DataFrames:

```
df_dict = dict()

for x in range(60):
    df_dict[f'{x}'] = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_dict['0'] =
```

[image]

#### list comprehension to concat the 4th column of each DataFrame into a single DataFrame:

```
df = pd.concat([df_dict[x]['d'] for x in df_dict.keys()], axis=1)
```

#### if column names are different, use `iloc`:

```
df = pd.concat([df_dict[x].iloc[:, 3] for x in df_dict.keys()], axis=1)
```

#### if there's a list of DataFrames:

`df_list` is a list of 60 DataFrames

```
df = pd.concat([x.iloc[:, 3] for x in df_list], axis=1)
```